# ftp - connection refused on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, ftp, localhost, filezilla, osx-el-capitan

If I run `ftp localhost` on Mac terminal, it shows the following result.

```
Trying ::1...
ftp: Can't connect to `::1': Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
ftp: Can't connect to `127.0.0.1': Connection refused
ftp: Can't connect to `localhost'
```

I already have apache installed on Mac, and I checked that out by entering `localhost` on the browser.

How do you diagnose this matter, and what should I take for the next step?

PS some people might ask me about the firewall. I checked that out as well in the system preferences and it's off.

Comment: You are running an FTP Server as well as Apache Web Server, yes?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes. I also tested `apachectl configtest` and I got the `SYNTAX OK` response.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer The answer to this question and [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/1028730/filezilla-says-connection-with-server-got-closed-prematurely-on-mac-el-capitan) is same which has been given by Jonno. OSX by default doesn't have FTP server installed but only a FTP client. You would need to download FTP module

Answer (score 0):

Apache Web server isn't bundled with an FTP server - you will either need to download [the FTP module](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp/en/ftp/) for it, or another FTP server, such as enabling the one included with [OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/29/start-an-ftp-or-sftp-server-in-mac-os-x-lion/).

By default, Apache hosts a web server on Port 80, but not an FTP server.